# How I can calculate the sum of items that are stored in main Id and then sub_id in that main Id

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium-ide

Look at the image [image]

here you can see the Dom that how its showing one main div with ID and then item are there in that div.
I have to calculate all the items on a page that are shown to user. These items may vary from user to user so I have to calculate it.
Any solution for it?

Comment: To clarify, do you want the sum of all price tags, correct?

Answer (score 4):

Comments explain the flow

```
WebElement baseCard = driver.findElement(By.id("00automation")); // Finding the base of the DOM tree where the price tag will be
List<WebElement> priceTags = baseCard.findElements(By.cssSelector(".card-price-tag")); // Find all price tags elements

Integer sumOfPriceTags = Arrays.stream(priceTags) // For each price tag
                               .reduce(0, (sum, element) // Starting from 0
                                 -> sum + extractValueFromElement(element)); // Sum the current value with the price tag value
```

Comment: I have used the above code and its showing me error for Stream that String cannot be convert into integer. Then it give option to change List <WebElement> to int[], but once I do that it start to showing other errors as well.

Comment: Can you share on a gist your implementation of extractValueFromElement? It has to fetch the text and remove the dollar sign before parsing the string to an int.